# undefined local variable or method `new_media_path' - resources to resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have odd problem:

After starting server I got this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_media_path'
```

To repair this i must go to routes.rb and change

```
resources :media
```

to

```
resource :media
```

and again to

```
resources :media
```

It's annoying. Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try `new_medium_path` because `media` is plural form of `medium`

If you run `rake routes` you will see all available routes.

Comment: ..or change the routes to resources :medias. Not proper English, but it would give you "media" as the singluar, if you like

Answer (score 3):

You can also inform rails about the proper pluralization using the Inflector class. It handles most works fine, but non-standard pluralizations like 'media' aren't always pre-defined. To add your own, edit **config/initializers/inflections.rb**, and add this at the end:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.irregular 'medium', 'media'
end
```

This should let Rails handle all the plural/singular stuff - note this will affect that it thinks DB table names will be as well, so it'll expect the model to be **class Medium**, and the table name will be **media**

To turn the plural and singular to the same thing (i.e. always 'media'), use:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.uncountable 'media'
end
```